# Return top record (or row 1) only from query

Tags: sql, sql-server

After many trails and tribulations I was able to write the following query.

```
SELECT        repName.repID, repName.Rep_Name, Positions.Position, repName.Roster, DataSheet.ENTERED
FROM            DataSheet INNER JOIN
                             repName ON DataSheet.EE_ID = repName.repID INNER JOIN
                             Positions ON repName.Job_Code = Positions.Job_Code
WHERE        (DataSheet.ENTERED <= @ENTEREDEnd)
 GROUP BY repName.repID, repName.Rep_Name, Positions.Position, repName.Roster, DataSheet.ENTERED, DataSheet.ITEM_ASSIGNED
HAVING        (DataSheet.ENTERED >= @ENTEREDStart) AND (DataSheet.ITEM_ASSIGNED = @ITEM_ASSIGNED) AND (repName.Roster = N'YES')
 ORDER BY DataSheet.ENTERED
```

I am still feeling my way around SQL, and wanted to know if this query could be modified so that it only returns the top value or row 1. I want to send that value to a text box on my form.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return TOP N Rows just use the following

```
SELECT TOP (1)    /* rest of your query*/
```

You can also use PERCENT with your TOP Clause something like this

```
SELECT TOP (10) PERCENT /* rest of your query*/
```

If you have Same values in TOP N and you want all the rows TOP same values you can use something like

```
SELECT TOP (N) WITH TIES /* rest of your query*/
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention that I am using SQL CE, TOP is not supported by it.

Comment: IF SQL CE used this TOP(N).  You must enclose the Number with parenthesis.

Comment: @JoseM. Yep just checked it online like Jade has mentioned you need to make use of parenthesis the rest is same.

Answer (score 1):

**IF SQL CE used this TOP(N). You must enclose the Number with parenthesis.**

using Top N or Limit N in your query will return the oldest row because you order them using

```
ORDER BY DataSheet.ENTERED
```

If you wished to retrieved the latest row make your Sorting as

```
ORDER BY DataSheet.ENTERED desc
```

Answer (score 0):

depends on db flavor

mssql `select top 1`

mysql `limit 1` at the end

oracle `where rownum <=1`